# Dygraph annotations without series

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Reading the docs for dygraph annotations, it states that source parameter (alongside with x) is required.

But are there any ways to create an annotation without the series? I'm looking for a way to annotate on graph that some change occurred which is not related with only 1 series but will all.

My first approach was to use one random series, but this doesn't work when I hide the series or there is data missing only for this series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there's no direct support for annotations without associated series, there are a few workarounds available:

- Draw an indicator using an `underlayCallback`, ala [this demo](http://dygraphs.com/tests/highlighted-region.html).
- Use the "hairlines" plugin, ala [this demo](http://dygraphs.com/tests/hairlines.html).